# Assigning values conditionally (with multiple conditions)

Tags: python

As a follow-on to this original question:
[Python: Stripping elements of a string array based on first character of each element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485364/python-stripping-elements-of-a-string-array-based-on-first-character-of-each-el)

I'm wondering if I can expand this if statement:

```
with open(bom_filename, 'r') as my_file:
    file_array = [word.strip() for word in my_file if word.startswith("/")]
```

to include and 2nd condition:

```
with open(bom_filename, 'r') as my_file:
    file_array = [word.strip() for word in my_file if (word.startswith("/")) & not(word.endswith("/"))]
```

This generates a syntax error but I hope there's some alternative syntax I can use!

Comment: Do you keep in mind that the `word.strip()` will be executed **after** the testing so that `" /abc "` doesn't pass through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(bom_filename, 'r') as my_file:
    file_array = [word.strip() for word in my_file if (word.startswith("/") and not(word.strip().endswith("/")))]
```

You need to change

```
if (word.startswith("/")) & not(word.endswith("/"))
```

to

```
if (word.startswith("/") and not(word.strip().endswith("/")))
```

or with extra parenthesis removed: (as per @viraptor's suggestion)

```
if word.startswith("/") and not word.strip().endswith("/")
```

Note the `if(...)`, `...` must contain all the logic not just `if(word.startswith("/"))`. And replace `&` which is a bitwise operator with `and`.

Comment: The end of the string isn't stripped yet in the conditional check, so you'll need to do something like word.strip().endswith("/") or if your'e just stripping an endline, word.endswith("/\n").  Check out the *re* module for using regular expressions to perform more complex pattern matching on strings, e.g. re.match("^\/.*\/$",word.strip())

Comment: Also most of the parentheses are not needed. It can be just `... if word.starswith("/") and not word.endswith("/")`

Comment: @mtadd Good point, updated to reflect that the OP wanted to check for "/" exluding any possible "\n"